# Need to optimize this Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

My query takes too much time to fetch data. Each table (ap1, ap2, ap4) has 1626 records. Please help me to optimize the query

```
SELECT *
FROM ap1 w1,
     ap2 w2, 
     ap4 w4
WHERE w4.first_name = '2'
  AND w4.id = '303'
  AND w4.reference like '%AXS%'
  AND w1.first_name = w4.first_name
  AND w2.first_name = w1.first_name
  AND w1.id = w4.id
  AND w2.id = w4.id
  AND w1.number = w4.number
  AND w2.number = w4.number;
```

Thanks

Comment: Query is not syntactically correct.  Plus . . . you should rewrite the query to use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Dont use comma seperated JOINS. They are not recommended any more.

Comment: http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html

Comment: Syntax is correct, but as already said: switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh . . . It is not correct.  It will return the error that `w3` is an unknown table alias.

Comment: That's not a syntax error, it's a semantic error.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to write the query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM ap1 w1 JOIN
     ap2 w2
     ON w2.first_name = w1.first_name AND
        w2.id = w4.id JOIN
     ap4 w4
     ON w1.first_name = w4.first_name AND
        w1.id = w4.id AND
        w1.number = w4.number
WHERE w4.first_name = '2' AND
      w4.id = '303' AND
      w4.reference like '%AXS%';
```

This makes it clear that you want an index on `w4(id, first_name, reference, id, number)`.  And then on `w1(id, first_name, number)` and on w2(id, first_name)`.

However, this assumes that the join conditions are correct.  If you query is performing so poorly on small numbers of rows, then they might be wrong.  I would suggest that you build up the query one table at a time to be sure the logic is correct.